# How to get all the post categories under a post name in Wordpress?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am trying to get the Wordpress post with all of its categories under one line, but the problem is that it is repeating itself rather than outputting it in a single line. My code is

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT p.post_title, p.post_content , t.slug, t.name, AVG(l.rating_rating) as average, l.rating_posttitle FROM wp_posts p
    INNER JOIN wp_ratings l ON l.rating_postid = p. ID
    INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships r ON r.object_id = p.ID
    INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy x ON x.term_taxonomy_id = r.term_taxonomy_id
    INNER JOIN wp_terms t ON t.term_id = x.term_id
    WHERE post_type ='post' 
    AND x.taxonomy = 'category'
    GROUP BY t.slug,p.post_title
    ") or die(mysql_error);

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){


            $title = $row['rating_posttitle'];
            $rating = $row['average'];
            //$category = $row['slug'];
            $content = $row['post_content'];

            $query2 = mysql_query("SELECT t.slug FROM wp_terms t
            INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy x ON x.term_id = t.term_id
            INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships r ON r.term_taxonomy_id = x.term_taxonomy_id
            INNER JOIN wp_posts p ON p.ID = r.object_id
            INNER JOIN wp_ratings l ON l.rating_postid = p.ID 
            WHERE `rating_posttitle` = '$title'");

            while($row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($query2)){
            $category = $row2['slug'];

            echo "<br>";
            echo $title . "<br>";
            echo $rating . "<br>";
            echo $category . "<br>";
            echo "<br>";    
            }
```

What I get is:

```
Houston
4.0000
south


Houston
4.0000
central


Houston
4.0000
alternative
```

and What I want is,

```
Houston
4.0000
alternative, central, south
```

Any help would be appreciated ,

Thanks .

Comment: Note that by convention, the thing that we get back from the 'query' is the '$result', not the '$query' - and isn't this a duplicate?

Comment: As a side note; start using mysqli or pdo ;)

Comment: Yes it is but it's kind of different. I am asking something different here :)

Comment: this belongs on the wordpress site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){


      $title = $row['rating_posttitle'];
      $rating = $row['average'];
      $content = $row['post_content'];

      $query2 = mysql_query("SELECT t.slug FROM wp_terms t
      INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy x ON x.term_id = t.term_id
      INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships r ON r.term_taxonomy_id = x.term_taxonomy_id
      INNER JOIN wp_posts p ON p.ID = r.object_id
      INNER JOIN wp_ratings l ON l.rating_postid = p.ID 
      WHERE `rating_posttitle` = '$title'");

      echo "<br>";
      echo $title . "<br>";
      echo $rating . "<br>";
      $first = True;
      while($row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($query2)){
            $category = $row2['slug'];    
            if(!$first)
                  echo ", " ;
            echo $category ;
            $first = False;

      }
      echo "<br>";    
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked but now it is duplicating the whole values. for example it is outputting something like                      alternative, central, south, alternative, central, south

Comment: I have a feeling that has to do with your first query

Comment: what if you group by `t.slug` in your second query, do you still get duplicates?

Comment: I tried your solution by add group by t.slug in my second query and it solved my problem. Thank you so much :)

Comment: no problem, im glad it worked out for you